# Error in 'dplyr::summarize()': Problem while computing... Caused by error in 'sort.int()': ! x must be atomic

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, tidyr, summarize

System specs (running on an HPC remote cluster, so I cannot update R):

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26) -- "Planting of a Tree"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Package specs:

```
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.0.8’
```

Header of data frame `test_profile`:

| Obs_idx | Int | Min | Mean | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Obs001 | "all" | -0.255 | 1.242 | 2.487 |
| Obs001 | "(0.901, 50.5]" | -0.255 | 0.614 | 1.554 |
| Obs001 | "(50.5, 100]" | 1.196 | 1.870 | 2.487 |
| Obs002 | "all" |  |  |  |

And here's the first 99 observations for easier reproduction:

```
structure(list(obs_idx = c("Obs001", "Obs001", "Obs001", "Obs002", 
"Obs002", "Obs002", "Obs003", "Obs003", "Obs003", "Obs004", "Obs004", 
"Obs004", "Obs005", "Obs005", "Obs005", "Obs006", "Obs006", "Obs006", 
"Obs007", "Obs007", "Obs007", "Obs008", "Obs008", "Obs008", "Obs009", 
"Obs009", "Obs009", "Obs010", "Obs010", "Obs010", "Obs011", "Obs011", 
"Obs011", "Obs012", "Obs012", "Obs012", "Obs013", "Obs013", "Obs013", 
"Obs014", "Obs014", "Obs014", "Obs015", "Obs015", "Obs015", "Obs016", 
"Obs016", "Obs016", "Obs017", "Obs017", "Obs017", "Obs018", "Obs018", 
"Obs018", "Obs019", "Obs019", "Obs019", "Obs020", "Obs020", "Obs020", 
"Obs021", "Obs021", "Obs021", "Obs022", "Obs022", "Obs022", "Obs023", 
"Obs023", "Obs023", "Obs024", "Obs024", "Obs024", "Obs025", "Obs025", 
"Obs025", "Obs026", "Obs026", "Obs026", "Obs027", "Obs027", "Obs027", 
"Obs028", "Obs028", "Obs028", "Obs029", "Obs029", "Obs029", "Obs030", 
"Obs030", "Obs030", "Obs031", "Obs031", "Obs031", "Obs032", "Obs032", 
"Obs032", "Obs033", "Obs033", "Obs033"), min_value = c(-0.254732152867833, 
-0.254732152867833, 1.19606657841744, -0.581624397177908, -0.581624397177908, 
1.80285883686985, -1.32946116207892, -1.32946116207892, 0.0397515430616804, 
-1.86782725237575, -1.86782725237575, -0.363677468244763, -0.89468513981088, 
-0.89468513981088, 1.40224930998449, -0.182123025952034, -0.182123025952034, 
1.79700463006594, 0.0628927848954747, 0.0628927848954747, 1.25094254311538, 
-0.785768279069217, -0.785768279069217, 2.50315849464015, -0.267794081133244, 
-0.267794081133244, 1.31447315059208, -7.30734890513561, -7.30734890513561, 
-5.44985046139385, -1.70676638151362, -1.70676638151362, 0.175432359720823, 
1.15535062309171, 1.15535062309171, 4.00718195291599, 0.74803703859959, 
0.74803703859959, 2.41171554637094, -0.544609618466537, -0.544609618466537, 
0.821409713157584, -0.366926578002299, -0.366926578002299, 0.861453880987911, 
-6.88501280669894, -6.88501280669894, -4.92879267556576, 1.22826199907346, 
1.22826199907346, 2.95786185310986, 0.645333302644394, 0.645333302644394, 
2.07140449255131, -1.23893895235722, -1.23893895235722, 1.47787167045304, 
8.6996620109975, 8.6996620109975, 12.3737211099569, 0.752122732322617, 
0.752122732322617, 1.56607549494549, -0.704984743123576, -0.704984743123576, 
0.0198201682687236, -0.131726730960604, -0.131726730960604, 2.54861693952509, 
-0.63465862593846, -0.63465862593846, 1.39744177545714, 8.09507861455719, 
8.09507861455719, 10.7100409195007, 0.697597909614052, 0.697597909614052, 
4.22663723088679, -0.908276676629742, -0.908276676629742, 0.988216461685764, 
-0.53696857448957, -0.53696857448957, 1.73930496457536, -1.18816405717448, 
-1.18816405717448, 1.85709713270274, -0.620510841748233, -0.620510841748233, 
1.69402255505977, -0.113228887965414, -0.113228887965414, 1.46541944235744, 
-0.793721620714426, -0.793721620714426, 1.46107095464579, -0.852407986696068, 
-0.852407986696068, 2.4303445976372), max_value = c(2.48673182921488, 
1.55420993203703, 2.48673182921488, 3.62504011030173, 2.51310156228232, 
3.62504011030173, 3.42677271496997, 0.383129649599052, 3.42677271496997, 
3.74854434284627, -0.425522253262296, 3.74854434284627, 4.14918792025657, 
1.9640943196012, 4.14918792025657, 3.24163024948147, 1.82426350140434, 
3.24163024948147, 3.72058687493308, 1.36143417733632, 3.72058687493308, 
3.10811789516634, 2.82962855877036, 3.10811789516634, 3.88658390957774, 
1.63455622431031, 3.88658390957774, -3.48265080475278, -5.2813065556373, 
-3.48265080475278, 2.91550924747979, 0.136012216700982, 2.91550924747979, 
6.27230603652134, 4.35285188658044, 6.27230603652134, 5.01548205131385, 
2.37772331340597, 5.01548205131385, 2.68572236255961, 0.823911641772201, 
2.68572236255961, 3.81070437446827, 1.46191739229668, 3.81070437446827, 
-3.06234602308199, -4.56698564227954, -3.06234602308199, 5.43297302546367, 
3.37332708822159, 5.43297302546367, 5.04541443798249, 2.56699927860427, 
5.04541443798249, 4.17487988575546, 1.46297059443906, 4.17487988575546, 
14.1025751508761, 12.4183711272285, 14.1025751508761, 3.45571642112819, 
2.35498413696494, 3.45571642112819, 1.37141163846293, 0.0771421243145904, 
1.37141163846293, 5.05711251664516, 3.09005904310661, 5.05711251664516, 
3.89057979440823, 2.08286855290467, 3.89057979440823, 12.6696391427459, 
10.9926258281058, 12.6696391427459, 5.84626943044961, 4.42760801361144, 
5.84626943044961, 3.48397026129855, 0.843929695173952, 3.48397026129855, 
5.1566642614692, 1.9115744466407, 5.1566642614692, 3.19604056443681, 
1.48090214867976, 3.19604056443681, 4.11941927820203, 1.52324737728256, 
4.11941927820203, 4.21127609192633, 1.69927988323198, 4.21127609192633, 
4.47916917588721, 1.77279099521626, 4.47916917588721, 4.49666003774688, 
2.84005622902661, 4.49666003774688), mean_value = c(1.24177630116527, 
0.613774094518819, 1.86977850781172, 1.72605852593204, 1.02228992277848, 
2.4298271290856, 0.927629312914888, -0.35900994194761, 2.21426856777739, 
0.260747632756736, -1.27741512285249, 1.79891038836596, 1.64793457105727, 
0.342006572760482, 2.95386256935405, 1.57580461640916, 0.720286502261924, 
2.4313227305564, 1.61936014971212, 0.783787414798013, 2.45493288462622, 
1.88133634325819, 1.0110515853587, 2.75162110115767, 1.45577151776934, 
0.468044127106653, 2.44349890843202, -5.53666499085687, -6.40085356456282, 
-4.67247641715092, 0.379917337562594, -0.837871853672017, 1.59770652879721, 
4.00859832783524, 2.755221845611, 5.26197481005947, 2.8076894766256, 
1.69271005793619, 3.922668895315, 1.02488428644579, 0.110231245218908, 
1.93953732767268, 1.47368688718138, 0.601753394224174, 2.34562038013858, 
-4.95030152449466, -5.52438400696409, -4.37621904202523, 3.4762045542774, 
2.27032909064135, 4.68208001791344, 2.48318915060924, 1.67949143661966, 
3.28688686459883, 1.3566901287143, -0.0495390252963748, 2.76291928272497, 
11.832953173642, 10.5509159694863, 13.1149903777977, 2.02073800609225, 
1.45574073221913, 2.58573527996538, 0.228475362320769, -0.320386852160816, 
0.777337576802354, 2.58170496397582, 1.60780135441252, 3.55560857353912, 
1.72097524693806, 0.909946405551757, 2.53200408832436, 10.5136965135812, 
9.4556564914668, 11.5717365356956, 3.96592269432818, 3.02957202885995, 
4.90227335979642, 0.918245558162296, -0.0975065583862271, 1.93399767471082, 
2.08553574187197, 0.867443465962717, 3.30362801778122, 1.53536210718242, 
0.520851529584397, 2.54987268478044, 1.88018083505131, 0.725499972036272, 
3.03486169806634, 1.62466786983794, 0.988552032831021, 2.26078370684486, 
1.66130673635397, 0.665973440679618, 2.65664003202831, 2.03504771504409, 
0.807163462048844, 3.26293196803933), med_value = c(1.31570591336243, 
0.673117260882791, 1.96130502023471, 2.05177243873184, 0.984229033787678, 
2.20917174116832, 0.331756122986645, -0.417185268488787, 2.53441890665996, 
-0.394599860753529, -1.3098320597899, 2.01210614374166, 1.6847508613278, 
0.00888181214529415, 3.02114849399441, 1.81890785603417, 0.5955272528093, 
2.3243521934078, 1.2699077220455, 0.885849237191548, 2.36598796914253, 
2.59756459274135, 1.11847272962714, 2.73024329201096, 1.4890119865391, 
0.416355067311528, 2.24503352766485, -5.40582914372845, -6.3862895384795, 
-4.68395971180059, 0.155722288210903, -0.817169708329972, 1.79634751834489, 
4.21163816439579, 2.81780780592327, 5.41128067654851, 2.39471942988846, 
1.74097341883149, 3.96550684665566, 0.822660677464892, 0.0953509838222589, 
2.10243335948088, 1.28856716650256, 0.574059687768831, 2.49917982941475, 
-4.78914749712957, -5.28160804937772, -4.5880754589768, 3.05143813873319, 
2.18274705320577, 4.92239186637914, 2.28203660895734, 1.74941339926081, 
3.04768026050623, 1.47042113244605, -0.141957794089912, 2.66651279001467, 
12.3888718613563, 10.5022255529843, 13.0375571449821, 1.96046471239662, 
1.48674231357901, 2.6137990697891, 0.048481146291657, -0.307450111888204, 
0.712666771260362, 2.71242085963533, 1.59058092301575, 3.45522282084598, 
1.61880746120317, 1.00956090612484, 2.50356653528887, 10.8714662742399, 
9.5932358949005, 11.6128150958074, 4.29575375875245, 3.5189899495096, 
4.91076218850134, 0.916073078429858, -0.067208074588031, 1.55989399850389, 
1.84508489372872, 1.02839421743576, 3.56548201522565, 1.66899964069125, 
0.621088112458978, 2.52409810330148, 1.60863496617116, 0.920735252936729, 
3.19292747649624, 1.56671745218764, 1.13214647238373, 1.92457408922848, 
1.64420000259481, 0.886365615113318, 2.4164546710419, 2.56712532046386, 
0.810000452302254, 2.92633860312995), obs_range = c(2.74146398208271, 
1.80894208490486, 1.29066525079744, 4.20666450747963, 3.09472595946023, 
1.82218127343188, 4.75623387704889, 1.71259081167798, 3.38702117190829, 
5.61637159522202, 1.44230499911345, 4.11222181109103, 5.04387306006745, 
2.85877945941208, 2.74693861027209, 3.42375327543351, 2.00638652735637, 
1.44462561941554, 3.6576940900376, 1.29854139244084, 2.46964433181769, 
3.89388617423556, 3.61539683783958, 0.60495940052619, 4.15437799071098, 
1.90235030544356, 2.57211075898566, 3.82469810038283, 2.02604234949831, 
1.96719965664107, 4.62227562899341, 1.8427785982146, 2.74007688775897, 
5.11695541342963, 3.19750126348873, 2.26512408360535, 4.26744501271426, 
1.62968627480638, 2.60376650494291, 3.23033198102614, 1.36852126023874, 
1.86431264940202, 4.17763095247057, 1.82884397029898, 2.94925049348036, 
3.82266678361694, 2.3180271644194, 1.86644665248377, 4.20471102639021, 
2.14506508914814, 2.4751111723538, 4.4000811353381, 1.92166597595988, 
2.97400994543118, 5.41381883811268, 2.70190954679628, 2.69700821530242, 
5.40291313987857, 3.71870911623099, 1.72885404091919, 2.70359368880557, 
1.60286140464233, 1.8896409261827, 2.0763963815865, 0.782126867438166, 
1.3515914701942, 5.18883924760576, 3.22178577406721, 2.50849557712007, 
4.52523842034669, 2.71752717884313, 2.49313801895109, 4.57456052818866, 
2.89754721354865, 1.95959822324513, 5.14867152083556, 3.73001010399739, 
1.61963219956282, 4.39224693792829, 1.75220637180369, 2.49575379961279, 
5.69363283595877, 2.44854302113027, 3.41735929689384, 4.38420462161129, 
2.66906620585424, 1.33894343173407, 4.73993011995027, 2.14375821903079, 
2.42539672314227, 4.32450497989175, 1.8125087711974, 2.74585664956889, 
5.27289079660163, 2.56651261593069, 3.01809822124141, 5.34906802444294, 
3.69246421572268, 2.06631544010968), obs_rough = c(1.02443302484271, 
0.571580545153004, 0.42708797443795, 0.954117832103747, 0.458829791333984, 
0.479869210652184, 0.831351496820307, 0.426733856168461, 0.404060108000881, 
1.2381333607567, 0.464963386061988, 0.754553231413436, 1.0732269517239, 
0.405065232210955, 0.652068255920653, 0.765535104883084, 0.360975222849196, 
0.398244407829041, 0.972526073817875, 0.413502505182048, 0.468274206165265, 
1.0459656860554, 0.579958855998611, 0.443112658329619, 1.52098581249057, 
0.615112077793742, 0.899488226272018, 1.13841165265676, 0.556230099629927, 
0.563284896018361, 1.09507537455731, 0.532188175078786, 0.55296174273883, 
1.06850841086197, 0.465535827086933, 0.586175136469028, 1.05252516877193, 
0.467166654840705, 0.574197881284651, 1.21227097175732, 0.572048018397622, 
0.610778909294853, 1.24375169380877, 0.538636859278024, 0.645203902455177, 
1.23591565133224, 0.704338091419098, 0.517166849562803, 1.12380144216147, 
0.496076152944533, 0.624431347147114, 0.913475854824092, 0.269875836548257, 
0.632001488837635, 0.795724470071228, 0.270722789809929, 0.49541067923677, 
1.02240951960303, 0.495603061080694, 0.517834389086253, 0.94883990333614, 
0.473045962655727, 0.453011693478671, 1.29789429361051, 0.723768252236108, 
0.554357697115601, 0.952574818069477, 0.671922102047993, 0.259853841983267, 
1.07058538012007, 0.554785798221078, 0.476119433688362, 0.929385566682204, 
0.330933244141015, 0.596819453256262, 1.06179087262754, 0.547040715618292, 
0.512815499720356, 1.1152185272364, 0.548933149671357, 0.48164244408998, 
0.849662371081896, 0.360705810132252, 0.449423157889059, 1.243330603723, 
0.646151410640352, 0.536270492185523, 1.09700537907372, 0.492602115230773, 
0.596347341875593, 0.944330143046192, 0.440796595239547, 0.473516952000716, 
1.10076642300436, 0.432870154991159, 0.613173287352346, 1.07971777508736, 
0.544333536974537, 0.530789156483833), obs_auc = c(123.038548997389, 
30.0688680564511, 91.6768303193684, 170.859801482047, 50.2286048303078, 
118.654409267355, 91.9604603320349, -17.2226408033219, 109.196029789976, 
24.9545864306287, -62.8674956845195, 88.2013494325979, 162.990400238505, 
16.6455437736566, 144.926253571562, 156.338489775649, 35.1317253176906, 
119.380743029116, 160.044184226701, 38.731136812282, 120.256463105291, 
187.076746280454, 49.4855628256418, 134.738289015578, 143.652788730833, 
22.5899997122948, 119.416349997845, -548.177756588616, -313.661991128758, 
-229.057065484719, 37.1136199544588, -41.4041686016069, 78.3432507278474, 
397.259563113222, 135.029138664752, 257.964073858077, 277.885397030158, 
83.0406798880011, 192.470184521947, 101.438947402721, 5.37066780037201, 
95.2421544511086, 145.356632912738, 29.3453991502549, 114.892760806238, 
-490.072818878892, -270.457867852807, -214.879178321291, 344.303044603136, 
111.397587277469, 229.874821931139, 245.472851697096, 82.5868801940001, 
160.704434712708, 134.222054073263, -2.57740594139483, 135.185861985034, 
1171.88340036846, 516.952907046909, 642.455574038751, 199.98719030707, 
71.5954455449163, 126.740321492452, 22.5022492137562, -15.71147511024, 
38.1196670685311, 255.677551081243, 79.1152947313106, 173.972222425413, 
170.325889168382, 44.8783913951456, 123.724559884695, 1040.99946530262, 
463.239040391731, 566.664862299258, 393.360618252336, 148.917250926157, 
239.966987172626, 90.2466242431688, -4.9828582495832, 94.4389610847096, 
206.23384147382, 42.8372020526136, 161.664946870707, 152.517777634391, 
25.8904636560044, 124.95345522305, 186.142983270956, 35.6446966814664, 
148.916949135393, 160.412392488505, 48.8127995953674, 110.194440295883, 
164.519032173705, 32.9835282490597, 129.948920636025, 201.473587328397, 
39.3226691754278, 159.651013228007), obs_var = c(0.600806512905785, 
0.255283985416092, 0.153719435449037, 1.08869064895449, 0.94037066575354, 
0.248432386655089, 2.24393055976336, 0.164691538535049, 0.990513934960049, 
3.20157512214848, 0.129232831023725, 1.51079718567754, 2.40941177838791, 
0.722741608761001, 0.664747623623853, 1.00834680977627, 0.361107267362946, 
0.182468442931862, 1.13561193946795, 0.108881085100043, 0.76065774090287, 
1.47550268807028, 1.41521889400636, 0.0201935577434527, 1.46340900323892, 
0.341534587914212, 0.624117483394405, 1.0635361305303, 0.288032256900452, 
0.336618515142572, 1.97581084779848, 0.241440094931683, 0.723952201053315, 
2.28169782898232, 0.971035668678254, 0.432899524178261, 1.66479544590423, 
0.254189793832911, 0.572276302787944, 1.073095795897, 0.212360658960156, 
0.248403937187685, 1.25938730944598, 0.278435302503205, 0.714473718335507, 
0.734599861194399, 0.559470767213815, 0.252127530549841, 1.88437613550237, 
0.392989285850528, 0.446595898532936, 1.26382981541409, 0.316493905403436, 
0.918733649265663, 2.5527140846627, 0.335902177234366, 0.785947843636036, 
2.2895098556764, 1.02307483351598, 0.248344277259972, 0.589841768491147, 
0.238239781717556, 0.302008037307282, 0.39196425198238, 0.040508598582841, 
0.13662380749252, 1.53924118708249, 0.772348149093586, 0.401857023337526, 
1.20414497569501, 0.441529867885485, 0.64895124308932, 1.55250030981482, 
0.622614039175798, 0.229481100254455, 1.48981430809735, 1.06341800033901, 
0.157324032913164, 1.45651950847143, 0.306734787567093, 0.530412051440898, 
2.48469251631892, 0.753761121261158, 1.23827316144486, 1.39484583387243, 
0.545354285220635, 0.172330742280268, 1.79796602915277, 0.354743417781235, 
0.55688611986795, 0.815618141764237, 0.289582336905667, 0.532496443207762, 
1.71462729721187, 0.558721238316055, 0.883712750993734, 2.53883790224238, 
1.61693240685643, 0.435618173686979), obs_coef_var = c(62.4200264997, 
82.3195961915544, 20.9688313598045, 60.4500589849074, 94.8583261266684, 
20.5129787029824, 161.484276766739, -113.039224093296, 44.9469264982333, 
686.217001835744, -28.1419622294943, 68.3271889553305, 94.1923321411898, 
248.574787337861, 27.6018448997878, 63.723936453392, 83.4281931550774, 
17.5691711160355, 65.8069143263001, 42.0995965980332, 35.5267124761145, 
64.565951764858, 117.66261455102, 5.16437522553503, 83.0978224044124, 
124.862074414712, 32.331140506584, -18.6263550850169, -8.38460623942883, 
-12.4171486968346, 369.984533575101, -58.6444739606533, 53.2546992681212, 
37.6822237163683, 35.7652296707268, 12.5038797816462, 45.9548513203239, 
29.7849228621425, 19.2850704453578, 101.075154101964, 418.053937962525, 
25.6969213479881, 76.1507942117609, 87.6886937046773, 36.0359024530905, 
-17.3138546868825, -13.5395690143543, -11.4739006091762, 39.4892125445899, 
27.6122337458125, 14.2731073931354, 45.2725019671907, 33.4969204517575, 
29.1615131848275, 117.766135045849, -1169.92750682087, 32.0869668765826, 
12.7872781707867, 9.58657637570326, 3.7997856831829, 38.0064889968674, 
33.529193512084, 21.2532421033098, 274.021005361927, -62.820143471738, 
47.5503294160691, 48.0559014218441, 54.660571092465, 17.8287886525843, 
63.7624161037967, 73.0237665283233, 31.8157109047402, 11.8511477114883, 
8.34483527078968, 4.13975771913494, 30.776684038294, 34.0385241219082, 
8.09095919179267, 131.431455302979, -567.999153996238, 37.6574357642493, 
75.5820537848948, 100.086542423027, 33.6834904849878, 76.9223045200692, 
141.783411262445, 16.2803179651373, 71.3166803461187, 82.0955795192764, 
24.5891939280166, 55.5877181544594, 54.4360370185406, 32.2774592137682, 
78.8197477563374, 112.238196719039, 35.3852972433757, 78.2965976212478, 
157.537677374611, 20.2276288401341), interval = c("all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", "(50.5,100]", "all", "(0.901,50.5]", 
"(50.5,100]")), row.names = c(NA, 99L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code implemented (Note: this is one step within a loop)

```
test_summary_grp <- test_profile %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(c(-obs_idx, -interval), 
                 names_to = "summary_stat") %>%
    dplyr::group_by(summary_stat, interval) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(q1_stat = quantile(value, probs = 0.25),
                     q3_stat = quantile(value, probs = 0.75), 
                     iqr_stat = q3_stat - q1_stat,
                     u_fence = q3_stat + 1.5*iqr_stat, 
                     l_fence = q1_stat - 1.5*iqr_stat)
```

Error returned:

```
Error in `dplyr::summarize()`:
! Problem while computing `q1_stat = quantile(value, probs = 0.25)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: summary_stat = "max_value", interval = <"all",
  "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all",
  "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all",
  "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all">.
Caused by error in `sort.int()`:
! 'x' must be atomic
Backtrace:
     x
  1. +-global easy_out_fda(test_data = test_data, per_out = out_rate, n_ints = n_int)
  2. | \-test_summary_grp %>% ...
  3. +-dplyr::summarize(...)
  4. +-dplyr:::summarise.grouped_df(...)
  5. | \-dplyr:::summarise_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), caller_env = caller_env())
  6. |   +-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  7. |   \-dplyr:::map(quosures, summarise_eval_one, mask = mask)
  8. |     \-base::lapply(.x, .f, ...)
  9. |       \-dplyr FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 10. |         \-mask$eval_all_summarise(quo)
 11. +-stats::quantile(value, probs = 0.25)
 12. +-stats:::quantile.default(value, probs = 0.25)
 13. | +-base::sort(x, partial = unique(c(lo, hi)))
 14. | \-base::sort.default(x, partial = unique(c(lo, hi)))
 15. |   \-base::sort.int(...)
 16. |     \-base::stop("'x' must be atomic")
 17. \-base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 18.   \-dplyr h(simpleError(msg, call))
 19.     \-rlang::abort(bullets, call = error_call, parent = skip_internal_condition(e))
Execution halted
```

I am completely at a loss here. Things are made more frustrating by trying to resolve this on a remote cluster. More often than not, "'x' must be atomic" is tripped by trying to sort a list. Yet, as you can see above, I am not passing a list in. I even split the dplyr pipeline to get feedback on the state of the data frame right before the summarize step like so:

```
test_summary_grp <- test_profile %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(c(-obs_idx, -interval), 
                 names_to = "summary_stat") %>%
    dplyr::group_by(summary_stat, interval)
  
  cat("Class of test summary before summarize:",
      class(test_summary_grp), "; iter = ", iter, "\n")
  
  test_summary <- test_summary_grp %>%
    dplyr::summarize(q1_stat = quantile(value, probs = 0.25),
                     q3_stat = quantile(value, probs = 0.75), 
                     iqr_stat = q3_stat - q1_stat,
                     u_fence = q3_stat + 1.5*iqr_stat, 
                     l_fence = q1_stat - 1.5*iqr_stat)
```

But that did not uncover anything, as the cat message gives back:

```
Class of test summary before summarize: grouped_df tbl_df tbl data.frame ; iter =  1
```

To complicate matters further, the issue does not arise when I implement on my own machine with specs

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
```

and `dplyr` version

```
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.0.8’
```

There seems to be no rhyme or reason as to what trips this error. On one simulation, it happens on the very first iteration. Other times, it happens part way through. Then other times, there is no error at all, and the simulation runs to completion. I consider myself rather good at diagnosing these issues, but the added complexity of only tripping an error on the Ubuntu super computer, without being able to reproduce on my own machine, makes it extremely difficult to find the source of this error. Any ideas or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It does work for me (try to remove the `NA`s as well - if the blanks are NAs) in `dplyr` 1.0.8 and `R 4.1.3` i.e. `test_profile %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(c(-Obs_idx, -Int), 
                 names_to = "summary_stat", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(summary_stat, Int) %>% dplyr::summarize(q1_stat = quantile(value, probs = 0.25),
                     q3_stat = quantile(value, probs = 0.75), 
                     iqr_stat = q3_stat - q1_stat,
                     u_fence = q3_stat + 1.5*iqr_stat, 
                     l_fence = q1_stat - 1.5*iqr_stat)`

Comment: Also, just a request - when there is an error, it may be better to show the example data using `dput` so that others can test with the exact data you have

Comment: right? seems extremely strange... runs without an issue on personal computer, but trips that issue on the remote cluster.

Comment: The R version you showed is old for the first case.  In addition, there could be tidyr version differences.

Comment: @akrun so those values were not meant to signify NA values. I was just being lazy haha. But I've edited the question to include a `dput` of the first 99 rows, which should suffice for testing... And right, that's one of the hiccups with the remote cluster. I have no control over the R version there. But they have an interactive shell that I can use to try testing further on there. I'm in the process of it, but was hoping to find a few pointers towards where to look for resolving this issue.

Comment: The issue with tidyverse packages are that function that works in one version may return error in another version.  So, it is better to keep the versions same, perhaps dockerized option would be better

Comment: Your dput is working fine for me

Comment: alas, I should have started with testing on `3.6.0` before posting this question. the root of the issue was in how `test_profile` was created. there was a step in the loop that binds two data frames together, pending a pass of an if statement. When I combined them, I used `rbind` piped into `as.data.frame()` and R version `3.6.0` did not like that one bit.

Comment: `rbind` fails if one of the data.frame have slighly different column name

Comment: the column names were all the same, but the order of the columns was slightly different between the two data frames being bound. could that have been the issue?

Comment: In my version, the `rbind` is working fine though `rbind.data.frame(data.frame(a = 1, b = 2), data.frame(b = 1, a = 2))`

Comment: but what version of R? this was only tripped in `3.6.0`, and not on my personal computer running `4.1.2`

Comment: I tested on R 4.1.3, so probably the `rbind.data.frame` was not working in earlier versions with different order of column names

Comment: well I greatly appreciate the conversation! even though the solution came out to be rather trivial, it's helpful to get starting spots that I overlook. cheers, mate!

Comment: If you check the [news](https://cran.r-project.org/) there are lots of instances where they fix rbind bugs.  I didn't have time to go through all, but probably  this behavior was a bug which got fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After conversing with @akrun in the comments, I found the root of the issue: weird behavior in `R 3.6.0` when trying to do `test_profile <- rbind(df1, df2) %>% as.data.frame()`. If I replace that with `test_profile <- bind_rows(df1, df2)`, the issue does not appear.

In `R 4.1.2`, it seems it's easier able to handle `tbl_df` types when using `base` functions like `rbind`; yet in `R 3.6.0`, when using `rbind`, we end up with a data frame that has columns of lists.

I'll leave this here, because as @akrun pointed out, we should always diagnose with matching package and R versions!